# Second VGA Monitor “Input Not Supported”

Tags: display, vga, input

I've just attached a 2nd Acer monitor (G205HV) to my new Acer Aspire desktop (X195-UR21P) via a USB powered VGA splitter.  The standard monitor that came with the Aspire is working fine through the splitter but the 2nd screen shows "Input not supported".  I'm not tech savvy at all.  Is there an easy to accomplish way to get the screen working?  Primarily only Excel and websites on the second screen, no gaming or high res stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you switch the two monitor plugs?

Comment: just switched the plugs and same result.

Comment: You may have to configure your graphics hardware for dual monitor use. On Windows right-click on a blank area of the desktop and select Properties then the Settings tab.

Comment: I had this exact problem. I lowered the resolution for my secondary screen and it got fixed. Earlier I was trying to use 1920 x 1080. I changed to 1280 x 720 at 60 Hz and it got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The message "input not supported" usually occurs when you try to display a resolution which is not supported by the monitor.  Either because the resolution or the refresh rate is too high.

Your monitor can display up to 1600 x 900 pixels. How much are you trying to display on it?

---

Edited:

You did not confirm that you are using win7. If not, please edit your post to indicate which OS you are using. Assuming win7 for now. On win7 your get these screens when you right click on the desktop and select "screen resolution'

[image: Image of win7 right click on desktop]
[image: image of windows 7 'screen resolution screen" with part marked]

Do you have the 'Multiple displays' part? What does it show? Extend or 'duplicate these displays'?

---

Edit #2: *via a USB powered VGA splitter.*

A splitter as in a device which can not generate a second image, but which just copies the output from your original video card? That would explain it. Then your windows only generates on desktop and there is nothing you can do about it.

On the other hand, if you meant a device like a USB plugged GPU or one or something like the [matrox dualhead2go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/) then you should be able to get two different desktops.

Comment: Or the refresh rate could be too high.

Comment: Hi Hennes, I really don't know.  Don't need very high resolution for the tasks at hand.  Primarily excel.

Comment: just plugged it in

Comment: Peter, how can I address the refresh rate?  I'm not very knowledgeable.  I plugged in both monitors through the splitter and only the main one is working.  I can't scroll my mouse over to the second screen.

Comment: If you are using windows, right click the desktop and click on screen resolution. How many displays show up in the box?

Comment: showing 1 display

Comment: What happens when you right click on the original (well, only working desktop atm) and select properties, screen resolution. Does it show two displays, and if it does, can you tick 'extend these displays'? And which OS are you using. What I just mentioned is for win7. It is likely different for a different OS.  (You can add tags with the OS in question).

Comment: it's strange.  out of the blue the computer recognizes the 2nd monitor (G205HV) when I right click on the desktop and go to screen resolution.  my original monitor now has the lower resolution of 1600x900.  both screens are showing mirror images but I want them to be independent.

Comment: only showing the 2nd monitor when i right click.

Comment: the V243HQ monitor has higher resolution i believe.  I notice a decrease in image quality on the main monitor

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this message is because the resolution your current monitor is set to does not support the other monitor. You  need to lower the resolution in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on two pc's. replace the ps2 keyboard with a usb keyboard and do a detect, and that will fix it

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue, and could not fix it by changing the resolution. Leaving this here for people who will need to fix this issue.

I went to **Display Settings** > **Advanced Display Settings** > **Display adapter properties for Display 2** (the one that was not working).

The screen refresh rate was at 59. I changed it to 60, then "**Apply**".

My monitor turned on, but had moved to a weird 640x480 resolution. I changed it back to its native 1600x900, and everything was OK from there.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved when I use this information provided by MonsieurPoivron

The screen refresh rate was at 59. I changed it to 60, then "Apply".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1099331)